# Java DateTimeFormatter: DateTimeParseException with GMT-date

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I would like to parse an GMT-date like `Wed, 21 Oct 2016 07:28:00 GMT`with `DateTimeFormatter` into an `Instant`. To create the pattern i used the official documentation: [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

My code so far:

```
String date = "Wed, 21 Oct 2016 07:28:00 GMT";

DateTimeFormatter gmtFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE' dd LLL yyyy HH:mm:ss '''");
TemporalAccessor parsed = gmtFormat.parse(date);
Instant a = Instant.from(parsed);

System.out.println(a);
```

But every time i've got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed, 21 Oct 2016 07:28:00 GMT' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
```

At index `0` is `Wed`, I used `EEE` which represents `day-of-week` by definition, there are also examples which represent: `Tue; Tuesday; T`.

I've also tried lower-, and uppercase but not successfully. What is wrong? Did I overlook something?

Comment: Why not just use RFC_1123_DATE_TIME format?

Comment: Try outputting gmtFormat.format(Instant.now()) to see if you really get what you expect.  Can there be any localization involved?

Comment: @BobJacobsen i've got this error: `Unsupported field: DayOfWeek`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with the code

```
String date = "Fri, 21 Oct 2016 07:28:00 GMT";

DateTimeFormatter gmtFormat = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
TemporalAccessor parsed = gmtFormat.parse(date);
Instant a = Instant.from(parsed);

System.out.println(a);
```

But you have to change the day because otherwise it doesn't fit to the given date.

Answer (score 0):

EEE is the proper format for Wed. But it does not include the comma.

Try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter gmtFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss '''");
```

Useful [link](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm)

Comment: Didn't i excluded it by using `'`?

Comment: @SimonW. Not sure really. I usually write explicitlly the intermediate characters if present. Check this link, It may help http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm

Comment: Also what about LLL? I think the month name flag is MMM

Comment: MM is the numeric form "10" and LLL is the text form "Oct". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for redundant information:  The day of the week *and* the date.

Change the format to just ignore the first three characters, leaving it reading the day/month/year.